# Calender control in ASP.Net with textbox

Tags: asp.net, calendar-control

I wanted to use the calender contro with textbox. But when I tried using it with the help of ajax toolkit, I came to know that the respective libraries are not installed. Any solution to the problem...? I meant what can substitute the this?

Answer (score 0):

Try jQueryui UI datepicker. it's client side if that works for you. here is a link
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/